# Selenium, Java - Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

After chrome was updated to the newest - 109 version not able to run my test using Selenium. Could it be because of unstable version of chrome driver?

Here is my `Set Up` class:

```
public WebDriver driver;    `

    @BeforeMethod
    public void popUp(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/quart_alex/Desktop/com_preemAQA/chromedriver/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    }
}
```

I can't run my tests now, tried to download different available the newest versions of chrome driver.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger          (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Starting ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.74 (e7c5703604daa9cc128ccf5a5d3e993513758913-refs/branch-heads/5414@{#1172}) on port 46117
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'MacBook-Pro-Ihor.local', ip: '127.0.0.1'
Build info: version: '4.7.2', revision: '4d4020c3b7'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.7', java.version: '11.0.11'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []
```

Comment: My last chrome version is - Version 109.0.5414.87 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.